# Unable to escape the following Windows command properly

Tags: ruby, windows

I am having difficulty to escape this Windows command properly.

```
cmd.exe -c "ruby -e "File.open('c:\replace_me', 'w') { |f| f.write(File.read('C:/Documents and Settings/All Users/Application Data/replace_me')) }""
```

When executing the command like this below then it will work.

```
ruby -e "File.open('c:\replace_me', 'w') { |f| f.write(File.read('C:/Documents and Settings/All Users/Application Data/replace_me')) }"
```

Anyone can point me how to escape this command properly for Windows?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This particular case is dead easy, because you shouldn't need any quotation at all; all the special characters are already inside quote marks.  Try:

```
cmd /c ruby -e "File.open('c:\replace_me', 'w') { |f| f.write(File.read('C:/Documents and Settings/All Users/Application Data/replace_me')) }"
```

In the more general case you might need to use the caret to quote those characters that the command shell would interpret.  I think this would be right:

```
cmd /c ruby -e ^"File.open('c:\replace_me', 'w') { ^|f^| f.write(File.read('C:/Documents and Settings/All Users/Application Data/replace_me')) }^"
```

However, depending on context (i.e., on whether the entire command is itself being parsed by the command shell) you might need to double-quote:

```
cmd /c ruby -e ^^^"File.open('c:\replace_me', 'w') { ^^^|f^^^| f.write(File.read('C:/Documents and Settings/All Users/Application Data/replace_me')) }^^^"
```

The other question to ask yourself is whether you actually need the command shell.  In almost all contexts, the simplest possible approach should work perfectly:

```
ruby -e "File.open('c:\replace_me', 'w') { |f| f.write(File.read('C:/Documents and Settings/All Users/Application Data/replace_me')) }"
```